# background image displays fine on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, background-image

On my website my background image displays fine on firefox but on chrome there are large white boxes on the sides and those go away as the jquery image slide moves to the next image.I have the background image linked in the CSS to the body which all my content is in including the image slider.

**HERE IS THE LIVE WEBSITE**

http://wilsontsa.org/Technology%20courses/Technology%20Courses.html

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="bar">
</div>
<center>
<div id="pagecontainer">
<div id="container">
<div id="navigation">

<ul id="navigation">
<li id="techlink" class="dropdown"><a href="../Technology courses/Technology                 Courses.html" style="color:#046f83">Technology Courses</a>
<ul class="sub_navigation">
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Computer Science.html">&nbsp;Computer &nbsp;Science</a></li>
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Digital Video.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Digital Video&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="../Technology Courses/Technology Innovation.html">Technology Innovation</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Visual Design and Image Applications.html">Visual Design and Image App.</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Technology courses/Web Design.html">Web Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="englink" class="dropdown"><a href="../Engineering Courses/Engineering Courses.html">Engineering Courses</a>
<ul class="sub_navigation">
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Introduction to Engineering and Design.html">Intro to Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Computer Integrated Manufacturing.html">Computer Integrated Manufact.</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Principles of Engineering.html">Principles of Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Digital Electronics.html">Digital Electronics</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Civil Engineering and Architecture.html">Civil Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Aerospace Engineering.html">Aerospace Engineering</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/Engineering Design and Development.html">Engineering Design</a></li>
<br />
<li><a href="../Engineering Courses/I-Stem.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I-STEM&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="STEMlink"><a href="../STEM/stem.html">STEM</a></li>
<li id="weblink" class="dropdown"><a href="../Webmaster/Evolution.html">Webmaster</a>
<ul class="sub_navigation">
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Evolution.html">Evolution</a></li>
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Adapting.html">Adapting</a></li>
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Advertising.html">Business Model</a></li>
<li><a href="../Webmaster/Solution.html">Future</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<div id="tsa" class="TSA">
  <li><a href="../TSA Chapter/TSA.html"><img  src="../Images/Design Images/TSA-LOGO.png" width="50" height="34" /></a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
</div> <!--navigation div --> 

</ul>
</center>

<div id="spacer">

<div id="wrapper">
<div>
<div class="slider-button" onclick="ss.move(-1)">&laquo;</div>
<div id="slideshow">
  <ul id="slides">
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture1.png" width="900" height="300" alt="Coral Reef"></li>
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture2.png" width="900" height="300" alt="Sea turtle">
    </li>
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture3.png" width="900" height="450" alt="Coral Reef"></li>
    <li><img src="../Javascript Photos/Picture4.png" width="900" height="300" alt="Blue Fish"></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button" onclick="ss.move(1)">&raquo;</div>
  </div>
  <ol id="pagination" class="pagination">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-image: url(Images/Tech nology%20Images/bg_Tech.gif);}
```

**Slider CSS**

```
li.current {
background:#102c75;}


#slideshow {
float:left; 
width:900px; 
height:300px; 
border:2px solid #ccc; 
background:#fff;
position:relative;
top:16px;
z-index:-1;}



#slides {
position:relative; 
width:900px; 
height:300px; 
list-style:none; 
overflow:auto;
z-index:-1;}



#slides li {
width:900px; 
height:300px;}



.fader-slide {
opacity:0; 
position:absolute;}

.fader-fade {
opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:opacity .4s; 
 -moz-transition:opacity .4s; 
 transition:opacity .4s;}



#content {
width:900px; 
height:270px; 
padding:15px 18px 15px 18px; 
background:#fff;}



#content h1 {
font:22px Georgia,Verdana; 
margin-bottom:15px; 
color:#036;}

#caption {
background:#fff; 
position:relative;}

#caption div {
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
width:900px; 
padding:15px 18px 10px 18px; 
background:#000; 
background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);}



#caption h2 {
font:18px Georgia,Verdana; 
margin-bottom:6px; 
color:#eee;}

#caption p {
line-height:1.4; 
color:#aaa;}
```

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome v25 on my PC. BTW you're using the CENTER tag on your page which is now deprecated.

Comment: The HTML on your page for your NAV is a kind of broken at the end of the NAV code - check that out. You also have a DIV in there as a child of a UL which isn't valid HTML. You can only have LI elements as children of a UL or an OL.

Answer (score 1):

This is no good:

```
body {
background-image: url(Images/Tech nology%20Images/bg_Tech.gif);}
```

First off, the use of background-image is deprecated.  Secondly, Chrome isn't going to be able to identify that url because of the lack of quotes combined with the usage of a space.

(Right where it says: `/Tech nology%20Images/` - see that space?  That's a no-no.  The %20 can be a no-no, too.)

It should look like this.

```
body {
    background:url('Images/TechnologyImages/bg_Tech.gif');
}
```

NOTE:  For this to work, you're going to have to rename the directory `Technology Images` to `TechnologyImages`.  Which you really should be doing anyway, because it's not good practice to have spaces in directory names.  (Or file names, for that matter.  Use `-` or `_` if you must.)

Answer (score 0):

The slideshow that you have used seems to be breaking something other than that it seems to be working. If you look at the height of the body it seems to be about 90px. you could use jQuery to force the body down to the bottom of the page or put a CSS clear class at the bottom of the page.